# How to subscribe and publish parallel in Paho-MQTT python?

Tags: python, performance, mqtt, publish-subscribe, paho

I'm working with the paho-mqtt client and wondering if anybody of you can help me subscribing and publishing messages parallel. 
 
**My Setup:** I've got a couple of sensors writing data into an InfluxDB. Using subscriptions with some parameters (time, start of recording) I can afterwards get the sensordata out of the InfluxDB. I've wrote a script which subscribes to all *sensors/#* and hands me a list of all avalible sensors in my system, which leads me directly to my question: 
 **My Problem:** Now I've got an list of all my avalible sensors: *topics_list*:

```
 1. sensors/device1/temperature
 2. sensors/device2/gyroscope
 3. sensors/device1/gyroscope
```

also I've got a list containing the correct paramters for my InfluxDB query: *list_request*

```
 1. {"response":"sensors/device1/temperature","start":"2020-07T13:27:53Z","duration":"80s","interval":"1s"}
 2. {"response":"sensors/device2/gyroscope","start":"2020-07T13:27:53Z","duration":"80s","interval":"1s"}
 3. {"response":"sensors/device1/gyroscope","start":"2020-07T13:27:53Z","duration":"80s","interval":"1s"}
```

Now the workflow I've read about and used since now would be the following:

```
for i in topics_list: <br>
 1. connect client
 2. subscribe topic i
 3. publish message i
```

I'm wondering if anybody of you now how to initialise, connect, publish and subscribe in a parallel manner and doing so increase the performance.

Comment: Wouldn't this information be found in the documentation?

Comment: Threads, the thing you are looking for are threads....

Comment: By now I've got an additional question. If I'm right threads only make sense if I want to publish messages to different brokers. Does it also make sense using threads if the broker is always the same? The subscribed and published topics differ in my use case though. Or would it be an better approach to subscribe to a list of topics and publish afterwards using a normal loop? Best regards!